# How to link RDLC report viewer to data repository using unit of work pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, report, reporting, rdlc

I've created an MVC.net application using EF and the Unit of work pattern.  I followed this tutorial to create the unit of work classes:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I'm trying to create a report using the report viewer control. I understand MVC pages don't currently support the report viewer control so I've created a standard aspx page with the report viewer control.  I'm new to reports and I've been following this tutorial:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-an-asp-net-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx

However when I add the object data source to the page and try to select the repository, my repository is not listed. The unit of work class is listed but has no methods available

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd post my progress in case it helps anybody else.

First I created a stored procedure in the SOL database to get the records for the report with optional parameters for filtering.

Then I updated the edmx diagram to import the stored procedure and create a new complex class for the returned records.

Finally I created new report repository that sits outside the unit of work, like so:

```
namespace Project.DAL
{
    public class ReportRepository : IDisposable
    {
        internal ProjectEntities context;

        public ReportRepository()
        {
            this.context = new ProjectEntities();
        }
        public ReportRepository(ProjectEntities context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public List<Report_001_Result> Report001(string Status, DateTime? dateOpenedFrom, DateTime? dateOpenedTo, string caseTypeD, string subCaseType)
        {
            return this.context.Report_001(caseStatusID, dateOpenedFrom, dateOpenedTo, caseTypeID, subCaseTypeID).ToList();
        }   

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }     
    }
}
```

Once the project has been built the Report repository shows up the data selection lists for object datasources and in the report designer.

For each report i just add another method to this repository.

Not sure if this is the prefered approach but works for me.